# JAXB, MOXy, JSR-303, JPA - disable JSR-303 validations after unmarshalling?

Tags: jaxb, bean-validation, moxy

I receive an XML message via an external service that I am able to unmarshal into a POJO using MOXy as my JAXB provider.  I am currently able to persist the object using JPA (Hibernate) into a database and the JSR-303 validations work as expected when invalid data is encountered.

My challenge is that prior to persistence I would like to add two fields to the POJO - the user ID of the submitter and the date the record was received.  Adding the attributes works fine and everything persists as expected.  However as soon as I add @NotNull constraints onto the two additional fields (to protect writes to the same table from other processes) the unmarshal fails with the following error:

Constraints violated on unmarshalled bean:

Is there a way to disable the JSR-303 check after unmarshalling?  I have a large number of these I will have to create in the near future and having 2 different objects for every incoming message that needs to be persisted would be less than optimal.

Also - there will be other non-audit related information that will have to be injected later so adding a different auditing solution won't really help.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

To turn off BV in MOXy:

```
 Map<String, BeanValidationMode> props = new HashMap<>();
 props.put(JAXBContextProperties.BEAN_VALIDATION_MODE, BeanValidationMode.NONE);
 Class[] classes = new Class[] { Customer.class };
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes, props);
```

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/BVinJAXB/GettingStarted